# angular 6 event doesn't fire in form

Tags: angular

I work with Angular 6. I have the following attribute directive. I defined an event click in this directive.

```
@Directive({
selector: "[pa-attr]"

})
export class PaAttrDirective {

    @Input("pa-attr")
    @HostBinding("class")
    bgClass: string;

    @Input("pa-product")
    product: Product;

    @Output("pa-category")
    click = new EventEmitter<string>();

    @HostListener("click")
    triggerCustomEvent() {
        console.log("triggercustomevent")
        if (this.product != null) {
            this.click.emit(this.product.category);
        }
    }


}
```

I have the following form with four fields. I want to fire an event in the above directive when I click the input fields

```
   <form novalidate [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form)">

        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let control of form.productControls">
            <label>{{control.label}}</label>
            <input class="form-control" 
                [(ngModel)]="newProduct[control.modelProperty]"
                name="{{control.modelProperty}}"
                (pa-product)="newProduct"
                formControlName="{{control.modelProperty}}" 
(pa-category)="newProduct[control.modelProperty]=$event"


                />
            <ul class="text-danger list-unstyled"
                    *ngIf="(formSubmitted || control.dirty) && !control.valid">
                <li *ngFor="let error of control.getValidationMessages()">
                    {{error}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


         <div class="bg-primary p-a-1 p-attr"  > Total Price ccc {{totalPrice1}} </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
            [disabled]="formSubmitted && !form.valid"
            [class.btn-secondary]="formSubmitted && !form.valid">
                Create
        </button>
    </form>
```

In this form I defined in the input field

```
(pa-category)="newProduct[control.modelProperty]=$event"
```

Also I initialize product

```
(pa-product)="newProduct"
```

In the directive, I have

```
@Output("pa-category")
click = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

How can I fire an event in each input field form?

Answer (score 0):

You defined `product` as an input inside your `pa-attr` directive but you are treating it as an output in your template. You need to change `(pa-product)="newProduct"` to `[pa-product]="newProduct"`.

And you also forgot to use the directive selector on your `input` element.

Comment: I changed this, but I get Multiple markers at this line
- Can't bind to 'pa-product' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
- 1 changed line. How can I fire the event of p-attr directive

Comment: See my updated answer you forgot the directive selector. If you're still unsure how angular works, you really should go through the tutorial on angular.io.

Comment: I follow the book of Apress Pro Angular 6. I defined the pa-attr in the input and now the event fires